# Invalid XML feed from DocuSign Connect

Tags: docusignapi

When using Connect to receive a docusign envelope via a web service we have received invalid XML for one of our envelopes.  Personal data and PDFBytes have been removed from this copy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"><EnvelopeStatus><RecipientStatuses><RecipientStatus><Type>Signer</Type><Email>@ymail.com</Email><UserName>o</UserName><RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder><Sent>2013-07-03T13:36:59.257</Sent><Delivered>2013-07-04T09:35:13.23</Delivered><Signed>2013-07-04T10:01:21.447</Signed><DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" /><Status>Completed</Status><RecipientIPAddress>_</RecipientIPAddress><CustomFields /><TabStatuses><TabStatus><TabType>Custom</TabType><Status>Signed</Status><XPosition>927</XPosition><YPosition>1162</YPosition><TabLabel>SSN</TabLabel><TabName>SSN</TabName><TabValue>_</TabValue><DocumentID>1</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber><ValidationPattern /><CustomTabType>SSN</CustomTabType></TabStatus><TabStatus><TabType>FirstName</TabType><Status>Signed</Status><XPosition>100</XPosition><YPosition>1166</YPosition><TabLabel>First Name</TabLabel><TabName>First Name</TabName><TabValue>_</TabValue><DocumentID>1</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber></TabStatus><TabStatus><TabType>LastName</TabType><Status>Signed</Status><XPosition>462</XPosition><YPosition>1166</YPosition><TabLabel>Last Name</TabLabel><TabName>Last Name</TabName><TabValue>_</TabValue><DocumentID>1</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber></TabStatus><TabStatus><TabType>Custom</TabType><Status>Signed</Status><XPosition>1072</XPosition><YPosition>1291</YPosition><TabLabel>Data Field 5</TabLabel><TabName>Text</TabName><TabValue>1</TabValue><DocumentID>1</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber><ValidationPattern /><CustomTabType>Text</CustomTabType></TabStatus><TabStatus><TabType>Custom</TabType><Status>Signed</Status><XPosition>664</XPosition><YPosition>1193</YPosition><TabLabel>Exemptions</TabLabel><TabName>Single</TabName><TabValue>X</TabValue><DocumentID>1</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber><ValidationPattern /><CustomTabType>Radio</CustomTabType></TabStatus><TabStatus><TabType>SignHere</TabType><Status>Signed</Status><XPosition>406</XPosition><YPosition>1420</YPosition><TabLabel>Signature 9</TabLabel><TabName>Sign Here</TabName><TabValue /><DocumentID>1</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber></TabStatus><TabStatus><TabType>Custom</TabType><Status>Active</Status><XPosition>756</XPosition><YPosition>1193</YPosition><TabLabel>Exemptions</TabLabel><TabName>Married</TabName><TabValue /><DocumentID>1</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber><ValidationPattern /><CustomTabType>Radio</CustomTabType></TabStatus><TabStatus><TabType>Custom</TabType><Status>Active</Status><XPosition>845</XPosition><YPosition>1193</YPosition><TabLabel>Exemptions</TabLabel><TabName>Married but Single</TabName><TabValue /><DocumentID>1</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber><ValidationPattern /><CustomTabType>Radio</CustomTabType></TabStatus><TabStatus><TabType>Custom</TabType><Status>Active</Status><XPosition>100</XPosition><YPosition>1208</YPosition><TabLabel>Address</TabLabel><TabName>Address Line 1</TabName><TabValue /><DocumentID>1</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber><ValidationPattern /><CustomTabType>Text</CustomTabType></TabStatus><TabStatus><TabType>DateSigned</TabType><Status>Signed</Status><XPosition>989</XPosition><YPosition>1493</YPosition><TabLabel>Date Signed</TabLabel><TabName>Date Signed</TabName><TabValue>7/4/2013 </TabValue><DocumentID>1</DocumentID><PageNumber>1</PageNumber></TabStatus></TabStatuses><RecipientAttachment><Attachment><Data>_</Data><Label>DSXForm</Label><Type>.xml</Type></Attachment></RecipientAttachment><AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus><EsignAgreementInformation><AccountEsignId>79e2c3d5-971c-4e7b-8b34-575e21896435</AccountEsignId><UserEsignId>ae45b756-aa08-44d6-bc46-be76ed123a5a</UserEsignId><AgreementDate>2013-07-04T09:35:13.213</AgreementDate></EsignAgreementInformation><FormData><xfdf><fields><field name="SSN"><value>_</value></field><field name="FirstName"><value>_</value></field><field name="LastName"><value>_</value></field><field name="Data Field 5"><value>1</value></field><field name="Exemptions"><value>Single</value></field><field name="Address"><value /></field><field name="DateSigned"><value>7/4/2013 </value></field></fields></xfdf></FormData><RecipientId>1c70c533-4787-4ed2-8d0f-3b56e5bad87a</RecipientId></RecipientStatus></RecipientStatuses><TimeGenerated>2013-07-09T07:02:59.5158647</TimeGenerated><EnvelopeID>daff200b-0d82-480a-83d1-e253d50e4cbb</EnvelopeID><Subject>_</Subject><UserName>_</UserName><Email>_</Email><Status>Completed</Status><Created>2013-07-03T13:36:58.523</Created><Sent>2013-07-03T13:36:59.303</Sent><Delivered>2013-07-04T09:35:13.323</Delivered><Signed>2013-07-04T10:01:21.507</Signed><Completed>2013-07-04T10:01:21.507</Completed><ACStatus>Original</ACStatus><ACStatusDate>2013-07-03T13:36:58.523</ACStatusDate><ACHolder>Onboarding</ACHolder><ACHolderEmail>_</ACHolderEmail><ACHolderLocation>DocuSign</ACHolderLocation><SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation><SenderIPAddress>_</SenderIPAddress><EnvelopePDFHash /><CustomFields><CustomField><Name>taskId</Name><Show>True</Show><Required>True</Required><Value>CDFA8755-1FE4-E211-80E5-005056A930BA</Value></CustomField></CustomFields><AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation><EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping><AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy><DocumentStatuses><DocumentStatus><ID>1</ID><Name>fw4.pdf</Name><TemplateName>W4</TemplateName><Sequence>1</Sequence></DocumentStatus></DocumentStatuses></EnvelopeStatus><DocumentPDFs><DocumentPDF><Name>fw4.pdf</Name><PDFBytes>_____________________________________________________________</PDFBytes><DocumentType>CONTENT</DocumentType></DocumentPDF></DocumentPDFs></DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>_____________________________________________________________</PDFBytes><DocumentType>CONTENT</DocumentType></DocumentPDF></DocumentPDFs></DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

The errror is after the first  closing tag, additional (different) PDFBytes and tags are given.

Why is data sent after the closing DocuSignEnvelopeInformation tag?

Comment: Your xml file is really hard to read, others would be more likely help you, if the formatting was friendlier to the readers' eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Republishing the XML for this envelope should help determine if it was a one off or if there's a bug with the Connect service.  You should be able to republish the XML through your DocuSign Console settings, if you do that do you still get malformed XML?

Comment: Thanks Ergin,  It appears that whatever caused this has since been fixed.  Republished several times when I initially got the malformed XML and got the same thing each time, but I am now getting properly formatted XML.